# How to check an elements elementType

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, elementtype

In Craft 3, I've got a service function that I'm passing either an 'entry' or 'category' element into.

I'd like to know how to differentiate between the possible element types; This kinda of works:

```
public function getElementType($element) {
  if ( isset($element->group) ) {
    return = 'category';
  } else if (isset($element->section)) {
    return = 'entry';        
  }
}
```

However I can't help but feel this is unreliable and hacky. Is there a better way to check an elements elementType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the PHP function [`is_a()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) in addition to the PHP function [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php).

This is a bit different as it also matches classes which have the class as one of its parents, e.g. an element class that extends `craft\elements\User`.

Example:

```
if (is_a($element, 'craft\elements\User')) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

or

```
if (is_a($element, craft\elements\User::class)) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Having arrived here from a Google search while trying to do this in Twig rather than PHP, I thought it might help someone in future to leave an answer, even though it doesn't address your question directly:

```twig
{{ item is instance of('craft\\elements\\Entry') ? 'This element is an entry!' }}
{{ item is instance of('craft\\elements\\Asset') ? 'This is an asset!' }}
{{ item is instance of('craft\\elements\\Category') ? 'This is a category!' }}
{{ item is instance of('craft\\elements\\User') ? 'This is a user!' }}
```

I find this especially useful in, for example, internal keyword search results listings templates, where the elements that were found might be of different types and you want to take different actions depending on the types.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no dedicated method on elements, but you can use [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php).

```
switch (get_class($element)) {
    case Entry::class:
        // it’s an entry
        break;

    case Category::class:
        // it’s a category
        break;
}
```

Comment: Just a simple question, would you mind to explain why you use 2 different functions here? I know the behavior of `::class` and `get_class` I would just like to know why you use `get_class(element) == Entry::class` instead of `element::class == Entry::class`

Comment: They are both very different, `::class` returns the fully qualified class name for a *class name* and `get_class()` the fully qualified class name for an *instance of a class*.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered `getElementTypeById()`

This pretty much does the trick:

```
  public function getElementType($element) {

    $elementType = Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementTypeById($element->id);

    if (strpos($elementType, 'Category') !== false) {
      return 'category';
    } else if (strpos($elementType, 'Entry') !== false) {
      return 'entry';
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Example: do nothing if element is not Entry

```
if (!$event->element instanceof \craft\elements\Entry) { return; }
```